# Julia REPL not opening up new plot window

Tags: plot, julia

I started learning julia recently and in my understading from reading up online, when you call some sort of rendering/plotting method in the REPL it should open up another window but instead what I get is a written representation of the plot, something like this:

```
Scene (683px, 384px):
  18 Plots:
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.poly,Tuple{Array{Array{Point{2,Float32},1},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.annotations,Tuple{Array{Tuple{String,Point{2,Float32}},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.text,Tuple{String}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.lines,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.linesegments,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.annotations,Tuple{Array{Tuple{String,Point{2,Float32}},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.text,Tuple{String}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.lines,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.lines,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    ├ Combined{AbstractPlotting.lines,Tuple{Array{Point{2,Float32},1}}}
    └ Combined{AbstractPlotting.text,Tuple{String}}
  1 Child Scene:
    └ Scene (571px, 286px)
```

Here's the code for reference:

```
using GLMakie
AbstractPlotting.inline!(true)

points = [Point2f0(cos(t), sin(t)) for t in LinRange(0, 2pi, 20)]
colors = 1:20
figure, axis, scatterobject = scatter(points, color = colors, markersize = 15)
figure
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's this or if this is actually supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rendering the plot in an external window from the REPL avoid the line `AbstractPlotting.inline!` or set it to `false`.

`AbstractPlotting.inline!(true)` is needed for [displaying plots in IJulia or Jupyther notebooks](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/blob/master/#user-content-using-ijulia--jupyter-notebook-with-makie).

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. I'm still having the same problem with the Agents.jl framework, since I can't seem to find an equivalent option, but it shouldn't be hard